# What is the name of the other symbiotes in Venom?

Tags: plot-explanation, venom

In the beginning of the movie Venom, there are a total of four symbiotes. One escaped in the crash and hopped from one host to another. Later revealed that its name is *Riot*. The other three were taken to the lab. One of them is Venom.

And later it is shown that the other two are dead because they were unable to find a suitable host.

I was wondering what is the name of these symbiotes? Is it ever mentioned in the movie or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

They remained unnamed in the film but [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/venom-movie-villains-symbiotes/) tried to identify them:

> **PHAGE**
>
> Although Riot escaped, a number of symbiote samples were still obtained by the Life Foundation. This yellow symbiote is probably Phage, who's traditionally presented as a yellow/orange. Phage doesn't survive the Life Foundation's experiments.
>
> **TOXIN**
>
> The other symbiote alongside Riot, Scream and Phage is a blue and gold one, which - as initially shown in the Venom trailer - was set loose on unwitting test subjects. Not only is this coloring distinct from the others in the film, it also doesn't match up with any of the Five Symbiotes from the comics (Riot has a blue-ish tint but, as established, here is more pure silver). It looks to be the Toxin symbiote, a better-known character than any of the Five - and, ironically, in the comics the only symbiote to become a trusted superhero ally of Spider-Man.

Comment: Was Carnage in there anywhere?

Comment: @StephenR Kasady comes in end credit scene

Comment: isn't Toxin comes from Carnage(son or whatever) which initially came from Venom?  (Venom -> Carnage ->Toxin)